# How to use shared_ptr in extern C when use python to call the so file?

Tags: python, c++, c++11

I want to use C++ to make an so file on Linux,and use python to call the library.I use shared_ptr in extern C declare,compile success but get some error when call the library use python.
I create some cpp files,like these:
Calculator.h:

```
#ifndef HELLO_WORLD_CALCULATOR_H
#define HELLO_WORLD_CALCULATOR_H
class Calculator {
public:
    double add(double first, double second);
};
#endif
```

Calculator.cpp:

```
#include "Calculator.h"
double Calculator::add(double first, double second) {
    return first + second;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/memory>
#include "Calculator.h"

using namespace std;

double add1(double first, double second){
    shared_ptr<Calculator>calculater(new Calculator());
    return calculater->add(first, second);
}

extern "C"
{
    double add(double f, double s){
        return add1(f,s);
    }
}
```

And I compile the file use this command:
g++ main.cpp -fPIC -shared -o test.so -std=c++11
My python file test.py:

```
# coding=utf-8

import ctypes
from ctypes import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")
    lib.add.argstype = [c_double, c_double]
    lib.add.restype = c_double
    print lib.add(c_double(12), c_double(36))
```

And I run the program use python test.py in terminal.Then I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10Calculator6devideEdd
```

How to fix the bug?

Comment: Should it be `return calculater->add( )` in devide1() of main.cpp?

Comment: Also, why the use of shared_ptr in the first place? The shared_ptr is completely local to `devide1`, i.e. it's not really shared. You could just as well create `calculator` on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the Calculator.h file in your compile command: `g++ main.cpp -fPIC -shared -o test.so -std=c++11 Calculator.h`